# Counting clicks on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I have a `<a href="" > </a>` on a page on my webiste. I wanted to count the number of clicks on this link by the user and display it. How can this be done?

Comment: More context please. Where do you want to display the clicks (in the page?)? Are you using any server-side language?

Comment: Is it per-user clicks? or per-link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best way to represent a counter for each a tag on your document and store the data with jquery.data, increasing the counter on each click,

example shown in here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/ShlomiKomemi/dvdPd/13/

Answer (score 0):

href can have a javascript function call that can do the count and redirect the user to the original page.

Or you can point the href to a server side page that can do the count and redirect the user to the original page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496583/asp-net-count-download-clicks this might be helpful